# Delete all worksheets except the first x amount of sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete all worksheets except the first 20 sheets

I have this code - Which I thought was working, but I just run it now and it only deletes some of the sheets.

```
Sub DeleteAll()
    i = Worksheets.Count
    For x = 21 To i
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Worksheets(x).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sheet indexes change as you delete them. So when you have deleted sheet 21 suddenly you have another sheet 21 which is skipped and sheet 22 is deleted, etc.

One solution is to delete sheets in reverse order beginning with the last sheet. For example:

```
Sub DeleteAll()
    i = Worksheets.Count
    For x = i to 21 Step -1 '# <- please note the change here
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Worksheets(x).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Do While Worksheets.Count > 20
   Worksheets(21).Delete
Loop
```

Comment: This is, of course, the best answer, except it needs the `DisplayAlerts` bits.